# Regex on korean characters

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract korean letters before '로' and before '길'in that WORD using **regex**.

1. 장안**로**458번**길** 138  ->extract "장안" and "번"
2. 충서**로** 1600                ->extract  "충서"

I have [^\x00-\x7F]+(?=로) [^\x00-\x7F]+(?=길). but this is not working for all

Comment: Where are you going to use the regex in? Language? Tool?

Comment: There's various regex implementations - it'll help garner attention if you tag this question with the tool/language you're using

Comment: I am using C# language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\p{L}` to match any kind of letter from any language.

```
\p{L}+?(?=[로길])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jS0iI1/7)

- `\p{L}+?` Non-greedy match of one or more occurances of letters from any language.
- `(?=[로길])` Positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by `로` or `길`

Code:

```
String input = "장안로458번길 138\n충서로 1600";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\p{L}+?(?=[로길])");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
{
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
 }
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/V7dDza)

Comment: from the demo..it matched perfect. C# regex API I am using is returning only one match for the first example where as it should return two

Comment: In the same context.. how do we extract the numbers in between in a single regex..

Comment: could you ask this as a separate question.. So that you could explain briefly about the numbers you're trying to extract.

Comment: Need to wait 40 more mins to post :(